# Regex: Detect text that exists between <p></p>

Tags: regex

I have a plugin tag `[crayon ...]` that may or may not be rendered in a `<p></p>` block like so:

`<p>This is a <b>sentence</b> [crayon ...] The Crayon [/crayon] of words. </p>`

Since my tag is replaced by a `<div>` tag, the `<p>` is left disjoint from `</p>` and the browser closes it for me, leaving a blank paragraph above my plugin. In any case, the markup is invalid and has weird outcomes. My problem is that I need to detect if `[crayon` lies between a `<p></p>` block. I have found two ways so far:

1. Use `<p(?:\s+[^>]*)?>(.*?)</p(?:\s+[^>]*)?>` and search for `[crayon` in the capture.
2. Use `<p[^>]*>(?:[^<]*<(?!/?p(\s+[^>]*)?>)[^>]+(\s+[^>]*)?>)*[^<]*\[crayon` for the case of `<p>...[crayon` where ... doesn't contain a `</p>` or `<p>` and a similar method for a `</p>` after the `[crayon]` tag.

The second method is harder to read but will fail if a `</p>` is captured before my tag. It doesn't require any further processing to find my tag within the `<p></p>` like the first. However, the first regex is much simpler and will execute quicker. Which should I use, and is there a better way?

EDIT:

For method 2, this beast works:

`<p[^<]*>(?:[^<]*<(?!/?p(\s+[^>]*)?>)[^>]+(\s+[^>]*)?>)*[^<]*((?:\[crayon[^\]]*\].*?\[/crayon\])|(?:\[crayon[^\]]*/\]))(?:[^<]*<(?!/?p(\s+[^>]*)?>)[^>]+(\s+[^>]*)?>)*[^<]*</p[^<]*>`

Comment: I point you to [this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not). But regardless, if crayon can appear inside of a <p>, why are you using a <div> and not a <span>? If you want to correctly break the <p>, you'll need a proper HTML parser.

Comment: In wordpress my plugin must find and parse the `[crayon]` tag after wordpress has formatted the page, otherwise all formatting will be kept plain. If I format my tag before formatting, then wordpress will parse my plugin as well, making a mess of things. Since my plugin must be a div, this causes the issue. By wordpress formatting, I mean it adding <p> with the wpautop() function.

Comment: that kind of regex is known as "write once, read never"

Comment: :) I'd like to avoid doing both if possible, but it works. I'm not convinced that's a good argument to choose in favor of keeping it though.

Comment: I don't know much about Wordpress, but, quoting the [doc'm](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API): `wpautop recognizes shortcode syntax and will attempt not to wrap p or br tags around shortcodes that stand alone on a line by themselves. Shortcodes intended for use in this manner should ensure that the output is wrapped in an appropriate block tag such as <p> or <div>.` So maybe for your div-like shortcodes, ensure the tags are on their own lines? Otherwise, I'd create a `crayon_p` shortcode that will wrap in `</p><div> ... </div><p>` rather than go the regex route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit with improved regex, notice I also stole your open p tag detection ;). On PHP, had to add the `s` modifier for multi line match:

```
/(?<!<!--)<p[^<]*>(?:[^<]*<(?!/?p(\s+[^>]*)?>)[^>]+(\s+[^>]*)?>)*[^<]*\[crayon.*?\].*?\[\/crayon\].*?<\/p>(?!(\s)?-->)/s
```

The following string was used for testing. 5 matches expected, **179** steps taken (the single regex from question took **285** steps):

```
<p>This is a <b>sentence</b> [crayon]...[/crayon] of words.</p>
<p class="large"> Paragraph with parameters [crayon]...[/crayon]</p>
<p>[crayon with-parameters=true]...[/crayon]</p>
<p>
Multiline paragraph [crayon]...[/crayon].
Lorem ipsum.
</p>
<p>...</p><p>[crayon]...[/crayon]</p>
<!-- <p> --> This is a <b>sentence</b> [crayon]...[/crayon] of words.<!-- </p> -->
<pizza>yummy</pizza>
```

Any improvement?

Comment: `<li><!--<p>-->[crayon ...]`.

Comment: I thought of that, but it fails with this: `<p></p><p>[crayon]…[/crayon]</p>` by capturing the whole thing. The `.*?` following the opening `<p.*?>` will match anything until it hits a Crayon tag, but I only need it to match the open `<p>` before it. There could in fact be many `<p>..</p>` from the start of the string.

Comment: Also, I tend to now use `<p(?:\s+[^>]*)?>` because `<p>` won't match tags with attributes and `<p.*?>` could match `<pizza>`.

Comment: Thanks, also what regex program do you use that gives step measurement? I'm on mac using Reggy and RegExhibit.

Comment: I use RegexBuddy, on windows and on linux (works ok with wine 1.3.28). you just need to click on debug button and it shows regex execution step by step.